# Parse the data from Google Place api response in (Json format)

Tags: php, json, curl, google-places-api

How am i suppose to store the Hotel name and location from the response provided by google place api in PHP array. If my search string is ***restaurant in New York***.

The response of the api is in **json** format.

My script for sending the search request is:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['text']))
    {
        if(!empty($_GET['text']))
        {
            $search_text=strip_tags($_GET['text']);

            $hostname = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=$search_text&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDVdJtIAvhmHE7e2zoxA_Y9qWRpp6eE2o8"; 


            // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'


            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$hostname");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            if(!$res)
            {
                // error log
                echo'Unable to find results.';
            } else {    
                **// ALL output printing code goes down here**
                //$res=json_decode($res);
                //var_dump(json_decode($res));
                $obj=var_dump(json_decode($res, true));
                print_r($obj['"results']);




                }
        } else {
            echo'<h4><font color="red">Please enter the text to search.</font></h4>';
            }
    }
?>
```

Well, the output of the above code is something in json format. But i need to retrieve the Name of the Restaurant and their location from the json output.

So, Please suggest me a way to extract the exact output.

Comment: As a little side note, try file_get_contents() instead of CURL. It's much easier.

Example:

$results = json_decode(file_get_contents($hostname), TRUE);

Answer (score 2):

As I can see the results key contains arrays with the data you need.
Just do something like:

```
$jsonContent = json_decode($res, true);

foreach ($jsonContent['results'] as $result) {

    // now you have the $result array that contains the location of the place
    // and the name ($result['formatted_address'], $result['name']) and other data.

}
```

I hope you know what to do from this point.